# PHP/MYSQLi SQL SELECT on multiple table and return the result as json object

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, json, mysqli

I am building user status app where other can comment. I fetch the json result through ajax and then display it in my ap. however my problem is when i run the query it return only one run for each replies even though there are multiple replies for each status. Honestly i dont know whether the problem is from the PHP loop or it is from the SQL queries it self. I have battling with this since two days now and have search other Stackoverflow question for help but still. I will be glad if anyone can help me. Thank you.

User status are saved in the Status table and all replies on each status is saved in the replies table.

These are my tables

Users Table = gcm_users

```
   id
   name
   date
```

Status Table = gcm_status

```
   id
   userID
   status
```

Replies Table = gcm_status_replies

```
   id
   statusID
   userID
   replies
```

This is my sql statement

```
$sqlSelect = ( 'SELECT gcm_status.status,
    gcm_status.id,
    gcm_status.userID,
    gcm_status_replies.id,
    gcm_status_replies.statusID,
    gcm_status_replies.userID,
    gcm_status_replies.message,
    gcm_users.id,
    gcm_users.name

    FROM gcm_users INNER JOIN gcm_status
    ON gcm_users.id = gcm_status.userID
    INNER JOIN gcm_status_replies
    ON gcm_status.id = gcm_status.id'
    array(''), $conn);
```

PHP Loops is

```
       foreach ($sqlSelect as $row) {
             $respohnds = json_encode($row);
             echo $respohnds;
           }
```

I really need to help.

Comment: Where / how do you actually run the query?

Comment: @RandomSeed PHP, please kindly check the update question. I have corrected some of the table columns. I am using PDO to connect to the database

Comment: Show the code please. As it stands the loop iterates over a hardcoded array of 3 items, not a query result.

Comment: Run the query in a console or any other client to confirm the SQL is fine.

Comment: @RandomSeed yeah, the sql is returning results when i console.log it with javascript but as i said. i only get only one object from replies table on each status column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're generating a separate json object for each row, and returning them one by one.

Maybe you should do this instead to return a single json object encoding your whole result set as an array.

```
$respondhs = array();
foreach ($sqlSelect as $row) {
     $respohnds[] = json_encode($row);
}
echo $respohnds;
```

Comment: Thank you @Ollie it works, I only move the json_encode outside the loop